# Modeling of Multivariate Function of Dependent Variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, mathematical-modeling

In multi-variable calculus, if I write $f(x,y,z)$, it is assumed that $x,y,z$ are independent.

I'd like to model a quantity $F$, that is a function of 3 related quantities, $x,y,z$. In fact, $xy=z$. I thought about writing $F$ as $F(x,y,z)$, but this would be incorrect; in particular, $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ would be meaningless because when $y$ and $z$ are held constant, $x$ is constant as well.

What is the best way to model or express $F$ mathematically?

Comment: Why not defining a function  $$G(x,y)=F(x,y,xy)$$ so that $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$ $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial y}=\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+x\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}$$

Comment: x,y,z are not independent, if $xy=z$.

Comment: @JJacquelin I like your idea of removing the dependence on $z$ using the known relation $xy=z$. But I am confused by the last two equalities. Doesn't $$\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial F(x,y,xy)}{\partial x}$$ ? If I'm correct, what is the quantity $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ that you mentioned?

Comment: Use the chain rule for the total derivative of $F(x,y,z)$ : $$dF= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}dz$$ and with $dz=ydx+xdy$ $$dF= \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} dx+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}dy+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}(ydx+xdy)$$ $$dF= \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}+y\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \right) dx+ \left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}+x\frac{\partial F}{\partial z} \right) dy$$ and compare with : $$dF=dG= \frac{\partial G}{\partial x} dx+ \frac{\partial G}{\partial y}dy$$

Comment: Do not confuse $F(x,y,z)$  which is a function of three variables with $F(x,y,xy)$  which is a function of two variables. That is why, when one is not familar with this, it is better to use a distinct symbol $G(x,y)$ . Then, you are looking for $\frac{\partial G}{\partial x}$   and NOT for $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$   which not the same, because $\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}$   doesn't take account that $z$  depends also on $x$ .

Comment: Thanks @JJacquelin for explaining this to me - I'll let you know if I have further concerns.